# Access Collectionview footerviewcell outside of collectionview

Tags: swift, uicollectionview

How to access `footerview` buttons outside of `collectionview`?

Does anyone know how to access that button from outside of `collectionView`

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView
 {

    switch kind {

        case UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader:
            let header = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: kind, withReuseIdentifier: "cellHeader", for: indexPath) as! CollectionReusableView
            return header

        case UICollectionElementKindSectionFooter:
            let footer = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: kind, withReuseIdentifier: "cellFooter", for: indexPath) as! CollectionReusableView

            return footer

        default:
            print("anything")
        }

        return UICollectionReusableView()
    }
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What button are you talking about?

Comment: I have button in footerview like "logout". and when u was trying to use by creating object of footerview it will return nil value.

Comment: Do you want to access button or footerView ?